# Extracting text from webtable selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, html-table, gettext

HTML:

```
<tr valign="top"> 
<td> 
  <p align="left"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><img src="/images/printit.gif" width="57" height="69" align="right"></font><font size="+1">Your 
    itinerary has been booked!</font></b><br>

    <br>
    Please print a copy of this screen for your records. Thank you for choosing 
    Mercury Tours.<br>
    <br>
    </font></p>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to retrieve the text `Your itinerary has been booked!` and `Please print a copy of this screen for your records. Thank you for choosing Mercury Tours.`

I tried with using tagName and xpath to extract the texts and sort it.But is there some unique locator here that could be used here?

Comment: Coud you share more details table HTML thats why we could provide you unique locator...??

Comment: `<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" vlink="#666666" link="#000099">
<table width="492" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr> 
    <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top"> 
    <td> 
      <p align="left"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><img src="/images/printit.gif" width="57" height="69" align="right"></font><font size="+1">Your 
        itinerary has been booked!</font></b><br>`

Comment: Is here only single row in your table??

Comment: Its not a table per se but the text & img elements are arranged as a table with a single column.Can u pls refer to (newtours.demoaut.com/mercurypurchase2.php)

Comment: Use provided cssSelector or xpath, hope it works here..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to provided HTML of table row, I'm not sure what could be unique locator. May be, below provided `cssSelector` would be unique here to extract the text :-

```
tr[valign = 'top'] > td > p[align = 'left']
```

You can use above `cssSelector` , if it is not unique you need to share more details about table HTML. So I could provide you unique locator.

Or if you want to locate this element with text, you can use below `xpath` which would be unique :-

```
.//td[contains(.,'itinerary has been booked')]
```

Comment: Hi, i could not find any unique values in here that could be used with cssLocator

Comment: Values means attribute value or inner text??

Comment: As you provided HTML in the comment, if there is only one row in your table, provided cssSelector and xpath both would be unique try it and let me know... for selenium syntax that how to use it could you tell what programming language are you using??

Comment: attribute Value.im using java

Comment: Ok then try as `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[valign = 'top'] > td > p[align = 'left']")).getText()` or `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[contains(.,'Your itinerary has been booked')]")).getText()` and let me know

Comment: Thanks this worked.cssSelector/xpath only way to go getting data from table elements?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean table elements??

Comment: Did you want to get text by using table locator element instead of column locator element??

Answer (score 1):

many days ago,  i faced this problem. It has two approach to solve this proble

- using normailize-space of xpath. ẽample in my project, i have to get text in tr element with br tag
      String temp = td.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[normalize-space()]")).getText();

  - using javascript to get content with css selector.
    i used the first approach. Sorry if my english is not good

Answer (score 0):

Using Java, there is another generic way I usually prefer to use to read any given table data and the content in it

```
  HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> tableData = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
  HashMap<String, String> tableCellDataMap = null;
  WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("<table_id>"));

  /**
   *  Call this method to get Table Cell Data by passing WebElement table
   *  @Params table
   *  
   *  @author Fayaz
   **/
  public static HashMap<String, String> getTableData(WebElement table) {
  List<WebElements> tableColHeaders = table.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
  List<WebElements> tableRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

  // Start rowIndex with '1' because in the zeroth index we get 'th' tags   
  for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < tableRows.size(); rowIndex++) {
     List<WebElement> tableCells = tableRows.get(rowIndex).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
     for(int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < tableCells.size(); cellIndex++) {
         String tableCellData = tableCells.get(cellIndex).getText();
         String tableColName  = tableColHeaders.get(cellIndex).getText();
         tableCellDataMap     = new HashMap<String, String>();
         tableCellDataMap.put(tableColName, tableCellData);
     }
     tableData.put(rowIndex, tableCellDataMap);
  }
  return tableCellDataMap;
 }
```

Actually, it can even be further modularize to make Table utility with methods like, getTableHeader(), getRowSize(), getColSize(), getData(int rowIndex), getData(int colIndex)